# What term refers to "problematic situations of misunderstanding due to cultural differences"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In situations in which people of different cultures meet, it is people who are unaware of subtle cultural differences can easily find themselves in a situation. Here are two simple examples:

- Someone from a culture where people generally smile to passing strangers might assume, when in a foreign land, that the locals do not welcome their visit.
- A waiter expecting a tip might become angry with a frequently returning foreign customer unfamiliar with the custom.

Within communication studies, cross-cultural studies, or any similar field of study, is there a special term to describe these "situations of misunderstanding" which are brought about not by a language barrier, but by differences in culture, and a mutual lack of understanding of the culture difference by one or more parties involved?

The answers in [Word or phrase meaning 'Misinterpretation of tone due to language or cultural barrier'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147827/word-or-phrase-meaning-misinterpretation-of-tone-due-to-language-or-cultural-ba) do not fit this meaning:

- First, they have the connotation that "someone has made a mistake violating the norms of a particular culture", which is not always the case in these situations.
- Second, I am looking for a term that does not refer to a specific action committed by one person, but by the created situation.
- Finally, these words do not address the potential mutuality of the situation, but rather, connote blame on one individual.

Comment: You may have named it yourself: "cultural misunderstanding" seems quite clear. I'm not sure there is a special term.

Comment: As already explained in my post, the linked questions and answers in that other post are similar, but not what I am looking for.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_conflict

Answer (score 1):

While not from a particular field of study, various terms come to mind:

> - cultural confusion
> - cultural insensitivity
> - cultural faux pas
> - culture blindness
> - mores misunderstanding

There are also terms to describe the characteristic in a person exhibiting these patterns, such as:

> - chauvinistic
> - enthnocentric
> - self-centered